# How do I make a GridView display its data source's parent class fields

Tags: c#, winforms, interface, .net-3.5

This is probably a really simple problem, but I can't figure it out. I have this small line of code in my form's constructor:

```
 public FrmMain()
 {
    InitializeComponent();
    gdcSVN.DataSource = _presenter.GetAllFiles();
 }


 public List<IVersionedFile> GetAllFiles()
 {
    List<IVersionedFile> all = new List<IVersionedFile>();
    all.AddRange(_addedFiles);
    all.AddRange(_removedFiles);
    all.AddRange(_updatedFiles);
    return all;
 }
```

`gdcSVN` is a DevExpress GridControl. `GetAllFiles` returns a `List<IVersionedFile>`, which is defined as follows:

```
public interface IUserFile
{
    string Name { get; }
    string Path { get; }
}

public interface IVersionedFile : IUserFile
{
    long Revision { get; }
    SvnStatus Status { get; }
}

class VersionedFile : IVersionedFile
{
    #region constructors
    protected VersionedFile(string name, string path, long revision, SvnStatus status)
    {
        Name = name;
        Path = path;
        Revision = revision;
        Status = status;
    }

    public VersionedFile(string name)
        : this(name, String.Empty, -1, SvnStatus.Zero)
    {}

    public VersionedFile(string name, string path)
        : this(name, path, -1, SvnStatus.Zero)
    {}

    public VersionedFile(string name, string path, long revision)
        : this(name, path, revision, SvnStatus.Zero)
    {}
    #endregion

    #region IVersionedFile members

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Path { get; set; }
    public long Revision { get; set; }
    public SvnStatus Status { get; set; }

    #endregion
}
```

When I run the form, I only have 2 columns in my GridControl-- `Revision` and `Status`. How do I get the grid to show the inherited properties from the IUserFile interface?

**Edit** To clarify; I'd like my grid to show all 4 properties between my 2 Interfaces. `Name`, `Path`, `Revision`, and `Status`. Currently, it only shows the last two from `IVersionedFile`.

Comment: I am not sure but I think you should expose the inherited properties through public properties getters in your class. For instance, if you have an inherrited property of type string and name FirstName you should add public string FirstName{get{return this.FirstName;}}

Comment: @Christos I'm not sure what you mean. Isn't that what I'm doing at the very bottom of my second code 'paragraph', inside my IVersionedFile members region?

Comment: @sab669 what's the actual problem? What fields/properties do you want to show in your grid?

Comment: @KingKing I need to be able to see `Name`, `Path`, `Status` and `Revision`. Which are defined in `IUserFile`. I'm only getting `Revision` and `Status` as defined in `IVersionedFile` even though it implements `IUserFile`.

Comment: @sab669 Is Name and Path your inherited properties that you want to expose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact we usually use `class` for item type, `interface` is not recommended. Somehow the underlying base interface's members are not discoverable. I really think it should work in the way you want. I think you have to change the datasource a little by this code:

```
gdcSVN.DataSource = _presenter.GetAllFiles().Cast<object>().ToList();
```

That means whenever referencing an element in the `DataSource`, you have to know that it's of type `IVersionedFile` to perform some casting if you want, you also note that the underlying type is `VersionedFile`, `IVersionedFile` is just an interface via which exposing some properties (not all).

Comment: Casting it to a `VersionedFile` instead of `IVersionedFile` worked, thanks!